# The purpose behind the bit data in the Artemis ECS

Tags: java, entity, components, system, artemis

What is the purpose behind the `bit` member in the `Component Type`, and the `TypeBit` and `SystemBit` members in the `Entity` for the Artemis ECS?

These are some screen shots for the git repository of the Artemis ECS that refer to `ComponentType` and `Entity`:

For `ComponentType`

[image: For <code>ComponentType</code>]

For `Entity`
[image: For <code>Entity</code>]

[Here](https://github.com/gemserk/artemis) is the link to the git.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into https://github.com/gemserk/artemis/blob/master/src/com/artemis/EntityManager.java
-  at addComponent function. It calls

```
e.addTypeBit(type.getBit());
```

Also removeComponent() calls:

```
e.removeTypeBit(type.getBit());
```

So it's just an id for a component inside entity. The other id is for collecting component types in the EntityManager.

Anyway, it's a bit old implementation. Take a look at fork called [artemis-odb](https://github.com/junkdog/artemis-odb) which is greater in performance and actively [developed](https://github.com/junkdog/artemis-odb/issues). [ComponentType](https://github.com/junkdog/artemis-odb/blob/master/artemis/src/main/java/com/artemis/ComponentType.java) is also refactored.